# Which sanitization first? HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, sanitization

In class, I was taught that HTML Sanitization (HTML Encode) should be completed before running JS Sanitization (JSStringEncode) and this process should not be inverted.

Is the statement valid? If so, what could the benefit or reason for the order be? How does the order matter if the sanitizers are meant to do their own job?

Comment: Sanitization needs to happen when taking user entered data and attempting to put it into a database to prevent database injection risks. Data entered by users that is to be displayed in the page needs to be sanitized before putting in in the HTML to prevent script injection risks

Comment: Of course the order of sanitisation matters because the first sanitiser will modify the input that gets sent to the second sanitiser and they are santising with differing goals. However it's not clear what you mean by `JSStringEncode` and `HTML encode` – you should include links to – or better yet, or code from – examples of specifically what you are referring to.

Comment: @Intervalia I understand the risk involved for sanitization, but I am curious on whether if executing one before the other makes any difference.

Comment: @geoidesic I believe my professor is referring to generic encoding functions where the input is sanitized. I understand the input may different but wouldn't the goal be the same?

Comment: Encoding depends on what you generate: HTML encoding for HTML, Javascript escaping when you generate JavaScript strings, URL encoding when you generate URLs and so on. Applying more than one encoding when it is not required may produces content that doesn't follow the rules of the language you generate.

Comment: @axiac What happens in the case when you are sanitizing general user input to prevent injections? (Hence both sanitizers are required)

Comment: So this is a theoretical question based on a generalisation of unknown code... if that's the case then the answer can be whatever you want it to be :)  Show some code. You will probably answer your own question in the process.

Comment: Sanitization and encoding are different things. Sanitization is about removing undesired or harmful pieces from input, converting strings to numbers (when numbers are expected), trimming unneeded spaces, changing all the values to follow the same format etc. It happens before processing the data. Encoding is about the dynamic data (sanitized or not) when it is used to generate content (HTML, JavaScript, XML, JSON, URLs etc), i.e. output.